# Run function in the background and clear a list

Tags: python

First time poster, long time reader! I'm new to python, but I do have experience with other languages, primarily php and javascript, etc - basic web languages. I've touched on OOP in PHP and have built some amazing web apps, but this is all new to me!

I am running a rpi 1 b+ with a LED matrix on it. I took the luma led example code for the silly clock and built in a few things that will add additional functionality, including a crypto ticker. I have a function to check the specified crypto prices and return a list. I am trying to run this function in the background every minute or so and then return a new set of data. The data is then parsed through the cryptoticker() function which then displays it. I realized it is not running in the background and stops after one run through. If I call the function not as a thread it freezes this poor, old rpi and everything waits for the function cryptocheck() to finish, so a background process is ideal.

I am having problems getting the background process to run repeatedly as a thread and attempts to clear the data variable seem to clear it everywhere - it processes the crypto feed once, then shows nothing if I clear it. Itf I dont clear it, then newest data never shows, and I dont want the data list to grow forever, I need to clear it once it has been used in the cryptoticker function

Here's the code (let me know what else I'll need to clarify, not sure if this is correctly posted)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from datetime import datetime
from luma.led_matrix.device import max7219
from luma.core.interface.serial import spi, noop
from luma.core.render import canvas
from luma.core.legacy import text, show_message
from luma.core.legacy.font import proportional, CP437_FONT, TINY_FONT, SINCLAIR_FONT, LCD_FONT
from luma.core.virtual import viewport
import requests
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import threading
from threading import Thread
import random
    
cryptos = [['BTC', 'bitcoin'], ['ETH', 'ethereum'], ['LINA', 'linear'], ['SXP', 'swipe'], ['TRADE', 'unitrade'], ['UNI', 'uniswap']]
data = []
showme = ''
run = 0
finishedPromise = 0

serial = spi(port=0, device=0, gpio=noop())
device = max7219(serial, cascaded=8 , block_orientation=-90, rotate=2, height=8, contrast=20)

def meetingReminderSoon():
    meetMessage = "The meeting is starting soon   ||   The meeting is starting soon   ||   The meeting is starting soon   ||   The meeting is starting soon   ||   The meeting is starting soon"
    show_message(device, meetMessage, fill="white", font=proportional(LCD_FONT), scroll_delay = 0.02)

def meetingReminderNow():
    meetMessage = "MEETING IS STARTING NOW   ||   MEETING IS STARTING NOW   ||   MEETING IS STARTING NOW   ||   MEETING IS STARTING NOW   ||   MEETING IS STARTING NOW   ||   MEETING IS STARTING NOW"
    show_message(device, meetMessage, fill="white", font=proportional(LCD_FONT), scroll_delay = 0.02)
    
def randomPromise():
    randomPixels()
    randpromise = (random.choice(list(open('/home/pi/ftp/promises.txt'))))
    randpromise = randpromise + '  ||  ' + randpromise
    show_message(device, randpromise, fill="white", font=proportional(LCD_FONT), scroll_delay = 0.02)
    randomPixels()
    show_message(device, randpromise, fill="white", font=proportional(LCD_FONT), scroll_delay = 0.02)
    finishedPromise = 1
    return finishedPromise

def randomPixels():
    runrand = 0
    while runrand < 20:
        with canvas(device) as draw:
            for i in range(38):
                x = random.randint(0, device.width)
                y = random.randint(0, device.height)

                # 'draw' is an ImageDraw object.
                draw.point((x, y), fill="white")
                time.sleep(0.0007)
        runrand = runrand + 1

def cryptocheck():
    global run
    run = 1
    data.clear()
    while 1:
        for i in cryptos:
            url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/' + i[1] + '/'
            response = requests.get(url)
            html = response.content
        
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            symbol = i[0]
            price = soup.find('span' ,attrs={"class" : "cmc-details-panel-price__price"})
            changeprice = soup.find('span' ,attrs={"class" : "cmc-details-panel-price__price-change"})
            
            if price is not None:
                price = price.text
            else:
                price = ''
            
            if changeprice is not None:
                changeprice = changeprice.text
                changeprice = changeprice.replace('(','')
                changeprice = changeprice.replace(')','')
                changeprice = changeprice.replace(' ','')
            else:
                changeprice = ''
        
            data.append((symbol, price, changeprice))
            
        return data
        run = 1
        timer.sleep(120)
    
def cryptoticker():
    randomPixels()
    # build the message
    showme = ''
    for row in data:
        for elem in row:
            showme = showme + elem + '  '
        showme = showme + '|  '
    
    if showme.endswith('|  '):
        showme = showme[:-4]
    
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("%-m/%-d/%y %-I:%M:%S")
    
    showme = dt_string + ' || ' + showme + '|| ' + dt_string
    show_message(device, showme, fill="white", font=proportional(LCD_FONT), scroll_delay = 0.02)
    randomPixels()
    show_message(device, showme, fill="white", font=proportional(LCD_FONT), scroll_delay = 0.02)
    randomPixels()
    show_message(device, showme, fill="white", font=proportional(LCD_FONT), scroll_delay = 0.02)

def minute_change(device):
    '''When we reach a minute change, animate it.'''
    hours = datetime.now().strftime('%I')
    minutes = datetime.now().strftime('%M')

    def helper(current_y):
        with canvas(device) as draw:
            text(draw, (16, 0), hours, fill="white", font=proportional(CP437_FONT))
            text(draw, (31,0), ":", fill="white", font=proportional(TINY_FONT))
            text(draw, (33, current_y), minutes, fill="white", font=proportional(CP437_FONT))
        time.sleep(0.1)
    for current_y in range(0, 9):
        helper(current_y)
    minutes = datetime.now().strftime('%M')
    for current_y in range(9, 0, -1):
        helper(current_y)


def animation(device, from_y, to_y):
    '''Animate the whole thing, moving it into/out of the abyss.'''
    hourstime = datetime.now().strftime('%I')
    mintime = datetime.now().strftime('%M')
    current_y = from_y
    while current_y != to_y:
        with canvas(device) as draw:
            text(draw, (16, current_y), hourstime, fill="white", font=proportional(CP437_FONT))
            text(draw, (31, current_y), ":", fill="white", font=proportional(TINY_FONT))
            text(draw, (33, current_y), mintime, fill="white", font=proportional(CP437_FONT))
        time.sleep(0.1)
        current_y += 1 if to_y > from_y else -1


def main():
    randomPixels()
    serial = spi(port=0, device=0, gpio=noop())
    device = max7219(serial, cascaded=8, block_orientation=-90, blocks_arranged_in_reverse_order=False, rotate=2)
    device.contrast(16)

    # The time ascends from the abyss...
    animation(device, 9, 0)

    toggle = False  # Toggle the second indicator every second
    while True:
        toggle = not toggle
        sec = datetime.now().second
        min = datetime.now().minute
        min = str(min)
        now = datetime.now()
        meetRemind = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
        dow = now.strftime("%a")
        dow = dow.lower()
        nomeeting = 'no'
        if dow == 'sat' or dow == 'sun' or dow == 'mon':
            nomeeting = 'yes' 
        if sec == 59:
            # When we change minutes, animate the minute change
            minute_change(device)
        elif sec == 30:
            # Half-way through each minute, display the complete date/time,
            # animating the time display into and out of the abyss.
            full_msg = now.strftime("%a %b %-d %-I:%M:%S %Y") 
            animation(device, 0, 9)
            show_message(device, full_msg, fill="white", font=proportional(CP437_FONT))
            animation(device, 9, 0)
        elif meetRemind == '09:13' and nomeeting == 'no':
            animation(device, 0, -1)
            meetingReminderSoon()
        elif meetRemind == '09:15' and nomeeting == 'no':
            animation(device, 0, -1)
            meetingReminderNow()
        elif min.endswith('1'):
            animation(device, 0, -1)
            cryptoticker()
            finishedPromise = 0
        elif min.endswith('3') and sec < 10:
            animation(device, 0, -1)
            randomPromise()
        elif min.endswith('5'):
            animation(device, 0, -1)
            cryptoticker()
            finishedPromise = 0
        elif min.endswith('8') and sec < 10:
            animation(device, 0, -1)
            randomPromise()
        else:
            # Do the following twice a second (so the seconds' indicator blips).
            # I'd optimize if I had to - but what's the point?
            # Even my Raspberry PI2 can do this at 4% of a single one of the 4 cores!
            hours = datetime.now().strftime('%I')
            minutes = datetime.now().strftime('%M')
            with canvas(device) as draw:
                text(draw, (16, 0), hours, fill="white", font=proportional(CP437_FONT))
                text(draw, (31, 0), ":" if toggle else " ", fill="white", font=proportional(TINY_FONT))
                text(draw, (33, 0), minutes, fill="white", font=proportional(CP437_FONT))
            time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=cryptocheck)
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
    main()
```

Comment: When you say `return data` in `cryptocheck`, the execution finishes. Is this your intention?

Comment: Ideally cryptocheck() would continuously run in the background every minute or two minutes. return data was put in to make data accessible to cryptoticker. as I dont think I was able to access it without "return data"

Comment: The question from @rassar was helpful - I removed the return data and the function keeps running, AND the data variable is read by the other function that needs it!! THANK YOU!